# How to print json array in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Following is my `json` response :

```
{"fname":"abc","lname":"xyz","email":"test@user.com","description":[{"city":"abcxyz","address":"AX","country":"US","date":"2020-02-01"},{"city":"abcxyz","address":"AX","country":"US","date":"2020-02 01"}], "city":"abcxyz","address":"DS","country":"US","Month":"12","Year":"2012"}
```

And following is my code :

```
success: function(data)
{                             
       var userinfo=eval(data);         
       alert(userinfo['fname1']; //display correct result
       alert(userinfo['description']['city']; //display undefined

       if(!$("#fname1").val())  $("#fname1").val(userinfo['fname']);
       if(!$("#lname1").val())  $("#lname1").val(userinfo['lname']);                                                     
}
```

In success function if I am trying to alert `alert(userinfo['fname1']` then its showing me the correct result i.e. displaying name but if I am trying to alert `alert(userinfo['description']['city']` then its showing me `undefined` in alert.

Then I tried using `each` loop but still its not working

```
$.each(userinfo['description'], function() {
alert(userinfo'description']['city']; //not working
$("#city option[value="+userinfo['description']['city']+"]").attr("selected", "selected");
});
```

Following is my html :

```
<select name="country" id="country">
        <?php
          foreach ($this->description as $country) {
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $country['country']; ?>" <?php echo ($this->params['country'] == $country['country']) ? "selected='selected'" : ""; ?>><?php echo $country['country']; ?></option>
         <?php }
         ?>
</select>
```

Can anyone telll me where I am going wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Is your json data correct? You have in `description` a list of objects with `city`, `address`, etc; but you also have some of the same fields directly in the main object (and others are different). Which `city` data matters to you, the main one or the ones in the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second approach is the right one, you should iterate over `userinfo['description']` because it's an array. However, you should access the current element of the iteration:

```
$.each(userinfo['description'], function() {
    alert(this['city'];
    $("#city option[value="+this['city']+"]").attr("selected", "selected");
});
```

You can use either `this` or an explicit second parameter to get the current element (the first parameter is the index in the array). Check the docs for [`jQuery.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) for more info.

BTW I second @closure, using `eval` is security-unwise. Use [`$.parseJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) instead (or `JSON.parse`, if your environment supports it) when you need to parse json-formatted string. In this case it's unnecessary, since the `success` callback already does that to you.

Comment: alert is working but `$("#city option[value="+this['city']+"]").attr("selected", "selected");` not working

Comment: @Ultimate Remember that you have many cities in the result. The `$.each` will iterate over them, selecting each one in succession (thus de-selecting the others). If this is not your problem, please post your HTML and maybe we can help more.

Comment: For city its done and working. But now I want to generate combo-box in jquery and want to iterate countries over there. I am modifying my post with html.

Comment: I modified the post plz check

Comment: Isn't there just a matter of doing `$("#country option[value="+this['country']+"]").attr("selected", "selected");`? I see no difference between the city and country cases. (and both suffer from the multiple values problem - only one will be selected in the end: the last one in the `description` array)

Comment: No I thing you getting wrong actually I want to add options to a DropDownList. i.e. country

Comment: @mgibsonbr: OP copied the same question to both of us (alert not working). If you want to take it on, I can leave it to you.

Comment: @mgibsonbr : I am trying something like this : `$("#country").append(
                                    $('<option></option>').val(this['country']).html(text)
                                );`

Comment: Finally I am done with this using : `$('#country').append( new Option(this['country'],this['country']));`

Answer (score 3):

You need to do:

> alert(userinfo['description'][0]['city'];

`userinfo['description']` is an array. You need to refer to element by index first. Once you have reference to the object, refer the attribute

I din't see any need of `eval`. Eval is a bad practice. You can write this like:

> var userinfo = data;

JQuery parses the response if right headers (`application/json`) are sent by the server or you have passed `json` for `dataType` parameter. Even default for `dataType` is `intelligent guess`.

Comment: alert in working but `$("#city option[value="+this['city']+"]").attr("selected", "selected");` not working

Comment: Above statement that is not working. I guess it is part of $.each function, right?

Comment: A wild guess without knowing your html, try $("option[value='"+this['city']+"']", "#city").attr("selected", "selected");

Comment: @closure I think the OP was trying to reply to [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14000204/520779). Anyway, I tested his code, and it works fine (assuming his HTML is like you and me are imagining). Your version works fine as well.

Comment: @closure: Both (you and mgibsonbr) of your answers really helped me and I want to help from both of you.

Answer (score 0):

description in an array you need to access using array index:

```
userinfo["description"]["0"]["city"]
```

Answer (score 0):

see this : http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/docs/closure_goog_json_json.js.html

this sure wll be help full :)